# Objects that are merged together have shadow in between them

Tags: modeling, rendering

I was making this backrooms scene and noticed on my first test render that some objects (walls) that I've connected to each other have more or less shadows in between them.
[image: Biggest shadow is in the left wall]

On layout view there are no seams and the objects are perfectly in line with each other but still in render it looks like there are shadows in wrong places.
[image: Layout view]

Joining these objects together makes no difference and it appears to me that blender seems to think that for some reason these objects should have different shadows / not share the same shadowing or something like that, again this is pretty much the first time I am using blender.

Comment: It looks like a shader problem. These kind of malfunctions occurs for example when you use Normal map with wrong ColorSpace.

Comment: or maybe those are merged cubes, you should delete the inner orthogonal faces in that case... and just in case try right click > shade flat

Comment: Maybe it's the _way out_ ;)

Comment: They are multiple cubes that are snapped together and it looks normal in layout mode but rendering seems to think that there is a gap or something between them. Sorry but I did not quite understand these solutions since I pretty much just started using blender.